# trying to set referer in browser but i get error in puppeteersharp?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I would like to set the referrer to *puppeteersharp* in *c#* but I get the error

> cannot convert from 'string' to
> `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`

this is my code :

```
Browser browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {

            Headless = false,
            ExecutablePath = textBox6.Text,

            //Args = { '--start-maximized' },
            Args = new string[]
            {string.Format("--proxy-server={0}",line)}



        });

        // Create a new page and go to Bing Maps
        Page page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        //await page.GoToAsync("https://music.apple.com/login");
        await page.SetUserAgentAsync("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36");
        await page.SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync("facebook.com");
```

This is the error that i get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkAko.png)

Comment: That error is a TypeMismatch error.

Comment: If you can see your code is not formatted correctly is there any reason you don't try an fix it?... It makes it easier (for people who might help you) to read

Comment: The error that i have is : cannot convert from 'string' to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>                                                   this is the line that contains the error : await page.SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync("facebook.com");

Comment: what's the extra http header you want to add?

Comment: @hardkoded  i want to change the referrer : facebook or instagram or .... , before going to any link  , how can i do it using puppeteer sharp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync` expects a dictionary with the headers to append:

```
await Page.SetExtraHttpHeadersAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
  ["Referer"] = "Bar"
});
```

Comment: @hardkoked how can i run my puppeteersharp code in windows 7 without having problems of websocket?

Comment: you can't :( sorry

Comment: @hardkoked  but i have found that in github :                                                            *If you need to run Puppeteer-Sharp on Windows 7 you can use System.Net.WebSockets.Client.Managed through the LaunchOptions.WebSocketFactory property*                                                                                    I want to add this to my code in order to work with windows 7 can you help with that please?